# Draw a Circle With Reverse Filling in Android

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

Not sure how to do this, or what the right terms are for describing this, but here goes:

I want to make a closing circle animation in my android app, much like the end of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaFzcYh06RA). I'm guessing what I need to do is somehow draw a black circle but instead of filling the inside of the circle fill the outside. How exactly would I do that, given the tools I have with Android's Canvas class?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using clipPath to achieve this?
I was working on the same kind of thing and achieved it by using clipPath of canvas.